# After comma text values are not capturing in the lightning URL

Tags: lightning, urlhacking, list-button

Display Type: List button

Content Source: URL

Code:

```
{!IF($User.UIThemeDisplayed="Theme4d",
   URLFOR('/lightning/o/Quote/new?navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FOpportunity%2F' + Opportunity.Id
      + '%2Fview&defaultFieldValues=Name=' + Opportunity.Name
      +  ',ExpirationDate='+ TEXT(TODAY() + 30)
      + ',OpportunityId=' + Opportunity.Id
      + ',AccountId=' + Opportunity.AccountId
      + ',BillingName=' + Account.Name
      + ',ShippingName=' + Account.Name
      + ',BillingStreet=' +  URLENCODE(Account.Billing_Address1__c)
      + ',ShippingStreet=' + URLENCODE(Account.Shipping_Address1__c)
      + ',BillingCity=' + URLENCODE(Account.Billing_City__c)
      + ',ShippingCity=' + URLENCODE(Account.Shipping_City__c)
      + ',BillingState=' +  URLENCODE(Opportunity.Account_Billing_State__c)
      + ',ShippingState=' +  URLENCODE(Opportunity.Account_Shipping_State2__c)
      + ',BillingPostalCode=' + URLENCODE(Account.Billing_Zip__c)
      +',ShippingPostalCode=' + URLENCODE(Account.Shipping_Zip__c)
      + ',BillingCountry=' +  URLENCODE(Opportunity.Account_Billing_Country__c)
      + ',ShippingCountry=' +  URLENCODE(Opportunity.Account_Shipping_Country__c)
   ),
    
   URLFOR('/0Q0/e?oppid=' + Opportunity.Id
      + '&retURL=' + Opportunity.Id
      + '&Name=' + Opportunity.Name
      + '&ExpirationDate=' + TEXT(MONTH(TODAY())+1)&'/'&TEXT(DAY(TODAY()))&'/'&TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))
      + '&BillingAddressstreet=' + Account.Billing_Address1__c
      + '&BillingAddresscity=' + Account.Billing_City__c
      + '&BillingAddressstate=' + Opportunity.Account_Billing_State__c
      + '&BillingAddresszip=' + Account.Billing_Zip__c
      + '&BillingAddresscountry=' + Opportunity.Account_Billing_Country__c
      + '&ShippingAddressstreet=' + Account.Shipping_Address1__c
      + '&ShippingAddresscity=' + Account.Shipping_City__c
      + '&ShippingAddressstate=' + Opportunity.Account_Shipping_State2__c
      + '&ShippingAddresszip=' + Account.Shipping_Zip__c
      + '&ShippingAddresscountry=' + Opportunity.Account_Shipping_Country__c 
   )
)}
```

It is working fine in the classic, When I used a comma in the shipping address field. But not working in the lightning.

Anyone knows What I am missing here?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hello Mayank - Have you checked the trailhead about [Lightning Alternatives for Buttons](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration)?

Comment: Hi Jefferson - Yes I have already checked in the trailhead as well.

Requirement - I have one list view button using in classic and lightning. When we click on the button it will go redirect to the URL which is creating new records and adding the default value. You check my URL code as mentioned above.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello Mayanak - Yes, indeed I checked the button, it seems that you want to redirect to a new record page with default values. I still believe that you should go for a more lightning complaint approach like [Quick Action](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.predefined_field_values_notes.htm&type=5) instead of URL Hacking.

Comment: I tested your button up until the custom fields you have and it worked (as long as I added it into Opportunity Page layout with Quote related list and I encoded the Names for Accounts and Opportunities. My suggestion is to look for alternatives and clarify a little bit your question with the behaviour and configuration you currently have. This might be related to lack of encoding for shipping address.

Comment: I also noticed that you are using the navigation location and background context (this are not documented as supported and can cause problems in the future).

Comment: Last piece of advice: check this [Launching Record Create Page with Default Field Values](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.links_useful_custom_buttons_create_record_dfv.htm&type=5).